# QThread::msleep() freezes program

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtcore

I'm trying to create a fading effect on one of my `QLabel` when the user saves their game.

So, i thought using a `QThread` would be perfect for the job but the only problem is `QThread::msleep();` freezes the program.

I've used this technique many times before to slow down a loop but, now it just decided to freezes my program until the loop is over.

Does anyone have any ideas about what's going on here?

I removed all the unrelated stuff cause this program is huge.

#### saved.h

```
#ifndef SAVED_H
#define SAVED_H

#include <QThread>

class Saved : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Saved(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();
signals:
    void reduceVisibility(unsigned short);
public slots:

};

#endif // SAVED_H
```

#### saved.cpp

```
#include "saved.h"

Saved::Saved(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{

}

void Saved::run(){
    unsigned short alpha = 250;
    for(unsigned short i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        emit reduceVisibility(alpha);
        alpha -= 50;
        QThread::msleep(250);
    }
}
```

#### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

// QThread
#include "saved.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    Saved *saving;

private slots:

public slots:
    void animateSave(unsigned short);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // QThread
    saving = new Saved(this);
    connect(saving, SIGNAL(reduceVisibility(unsigned short)), this, SLOT(animateSave(unsigned short)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

// Buttons
void MainWindow::on_Btn_Save_clicked(){
    QFile saveFile("save.txt");
    saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream out(&saveFile);
    out << user.getUsername() + "\n" + user.getLevel();
    saveFile.close();

    saving->run();
    saving->quit();
}

// Slots
void MainWindow::animateSave(unsigned short Visibility){
    QString visible = QString::number(Visibility);
    ui->Lbl_Saved->setStyleSheet("color:rgb(0,255,255, " + visible + ");");
}
```

Comment: You've made horrible mistake and changed run visibility to public. You should use QThread::start to run a thread. Do not ever call run directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have any ideas about what's going on here?

This is intended [(see QThread: QObject)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html). The receiver `MainWindow` is in another thread. Since the default connection is [`AutoConnection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), Qt will use a `QueuedConnection` and run the slot `animateSave` in the same thread as your `MainWindow` object.

However, you shouldn't use `QThread` at all. You don't want to do things at the same time, instead, you want something to happen *at (or after) a given time*. [`QTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtimer.html) is what you want.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    /* ... */
    myTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout(), this, SLOT(decreaseAlphaOrStop()));
}

void MainWindow::on_Btn_Save_clicked(){
    /* .. snip .. */
    alpha = 250;
    myTimer->start(250);    
}

// new slot
void MainWindow::decreaseAlphaOrStop(){
    alpha -= 50;
    if( alpha < 0){
        alpha = 0;
        myTimer->stop();
    }
    animateSave(alpha);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also lookup the documentation of `QPropertyAnimation` and hook it on the `QWidget::windowOpacity`. this is may be the most fitting thing for your problem.

for example:

```
void MyWidget::buttonClicked() // SLOT when button is clicked
{
    QPropertyAnimation* anim = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->Lbl_Saved, "windowOpacity"); // new animation, hooked on the labels window opacity
    anim->setDuration(2500); // use 2.5 seconds for disapearing
    anim->setStartValue(1.0f); // from full visible
    anim->setEndValue(0.0f); // to invisible
    connect(anim, SIGNAL(finished()), anim, SLOT(deleteLater())); // delete object when animation done
    anim->start();
}
```